# Stack view arrangement of controls percentage wise in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I am building an iOS app with a form and I am using stackviews. This is the example of what I want to achieve:
[image: Example stackview]

The textbox and button are part of horizontal stack view. What I need is a way to allocate percentage-like width to them. For eg, textbox would take 80% of total stackview width and button would take 20%.

Stackview's alignment and distribution property are set to 'fill'.

I tried adding width constraint to the button but I feel that its not proper way of doing it as width would differ for different screen sizes.

Comment: To clarify, you're using a horizontal stack view here for a basically static layout, i.e., you're always displaying these two items.

Answer (score 4):

You can use "Equal Width" property and assign respective multiplier of 0.80 and 0.20 to the child views.

Please check below steps:

```
1. Select textbox and Stackview and assign "Equal width" contraints to it.
2. Then select the contraints and edit it by applying multiplier of 0.80 to the textbox contraints.
3. Then select button and Stackview and assign "Equal Width" contraints to it.
4. Then select the contraints and edit it by applying multiplier of 0.20 to the button contraints.
```

With above solution width will be distributed percentage wise in all screen sizes.

For more info refer this page:
https://jascode.wordpress.com/2019/08/15/weight-assignment-in-stack-viewpercentage-wise-size-calculation/

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `UIStackViewDistributionFillProportionally` setting.

This will use the proportion between the intrinsic content sizes of the view as the proportion between their actual sizes. So, for 80% to 20%, make one view 80 wide and one view 20 wide (in their `intrinsicContentSize` overrides), and they will be resized in the proportion of 80-to-20.

Comment: This helps sometimes but it does not guarantee to be fixed width. If content expands on textbox, button gets shortened.

Comment: @RujootaShah If that is happening, then it sounds like you are not overriding the intrinsic content size correctly.